# Solving set of 2 equations with 3 variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm working through an example and my answer is not coming out right. 
Two equations are given and then the solution is shown.

Equations:

$$\begin{aligned}20q_{1}+15q_{2}+7.5q_{3}&=10\\
q_{1}+q_{2}+q_{3}&=1\end{aligned}$$

Solution Given:

$(X, (1/3)(1-5X), (1/3)(2+2X))$ for arbitrary $X$.

I set up a matrix and solved and my solution is

$((3/2)X+1,(-5/2)X-2,X)$

What's going on here?

Comment: Your solution is wrong because the sum of the three does not equal $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix representing the system is
$$(A|B) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & 3 & 1.5 & 2\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right) \longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & 3 & 1.5 & 2\\
-1.5 & -1.5 & -1.5 & -1.5
\end{array}\right) \longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & 3 & 1.5 & 2\\
2.5 & 1.5 & 0 & 0.5
\end{array}\right)$$

where we see that
$$2.5q_1 + 1.5q_2 = 0.5 \implies q_2 = \frac13 - \frac53q_1.$$

Substituting into the first equation we get
$$4q_1 + 1 - 5q_1 + 1.5q_3 = 2 \implies q_3 = \frac23 + \frac23q_1.$$

Now let $q_1 = X$ and the set of solutions is
$$\left\{\left(X, \frac13 - \frac53X, \frac23 + \frac23X\right)\colon X \in \mathbb R\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we write 
$$4q_1+3q_2+1.5q_3=2$$
$$q_1+q_2+q_3=1$$
multiplying the second equation by $$-1.5$$ and adding this to the first one we get
$$2.5q_1+1.5q_2=0.5$$
or
$$5q_1+3q_2=1$$
we get $$q_1=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3}{5}q_2$$
setting $q_2=5x$ we get $q_1=1/5-3x$ and $$q_3=1+3x-1/5-5x=4/5-2x$$

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the matrix equation correctly?

$$\pmatrix{20 & 15 &7.5\\ 1 & 1 & 1}\pmatrix{q_1 \\ q_2\\ q_3} = \pmatrix{10\\1}$$

When I solve it, I get

$q=\pmatrix{-1+\frac{3}{2}X\\2-\frac{5}{2}X\\X}$

Note that you can confirm you did your math wrong somewhere because in your answer $q_1+q_2+q_3 \neq 1$ for every $X$. It does for both mine and the solution (which are in fact the same).

Comment: that solution is the one i got

Comment: It is correct then. This is different than the original answer you got. It is the same as the "solution" given; the only difference is that $q_1$ was chosen as the free variable instead of $q_3$ to use when solving for the other variables.